# PHP string '==' returns false on same strings

Tags: php, cookies

I have the code which checks user cookies:

```
echo 'prev: ' . $prevCookie;
echo 'curr: ' . $currentCookie;
if ((string) $prevCookie == (string)$currentCookie) {
  echo 'same cookies';
} else {
  echo 'different cookies';
}
```

In approximatelly 0.1% of cases I'm getting following:

```
// prev: xxx
// curr: xxx
// different cookies
```

How that stuff can be happening?

PS. Strings are trimmed, no extra spaces.

UPDATE

I can provide you with real values which are stored in db, but they're the same:
(direct), (organic), YandexCPC etc. It would be very easy if I could to reproduce it somehow.

Comment: Does `echo strlen($prevCookie);` and `echo strlen($currentCookie);` produce the same result?

Comment: do `var_dump($prevCookie)` and `var_dump($currentCookie)` and post the results in your question

Comment: 0.1% of the time the strings are not the same.

Comment: Maybe this question can provide a clue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562703/make-encoding-uniform-before-comparing-strings-in-php

Comment: Good question. I don't know yet, strings are logged in json_encode and they are the same there.

Comment: What @MonkeyZeus says might be something to look at.  But if you want a literal comparison of cookies I'd just hash them and compare the hashes.  
`md5($cookie1) === md5($cookie2)`  This way you don't have to care about removing spaces or other erroneous data.  If the cookies aren't absolutely the same, then they're different.

Comment: Related, [String comparison using == vs. strcmp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3333353).

Comment: What is your PHP version? Are you using UTF-8 **everywhere**?

Comment: @jww With MD5 it is possible that another cookie value generates the same hash!

Comment: @survex - please provide *real* values for `prev` and `curr`. Otherwise, based on what you posted (*"XXX"*), they are equal and this question should be closed as unable to duplicate.

Comment: Still waiting on the data requested in the first two comments. Please add them or expect close votes since we do not have enough information to answer this question.

Comment: @survex Looks like the two strings seemingly equal have something different that is not visible, it might be a leading or suffixed space, or a `\0` anywhere. There are symbols that might not print or not be noticed when printed that will cause two strings to be logically different but look the same.

Comment: @Havenard  in addition to your comment: or a zero width space.

Comment: @GuyT - I think this question is about two strings that are supposed to be equal, and not two different strings and hashing collisions. But I would like to hear about how the collisions are being generated, even with MD5.

Comment: @jww wait a minute, I will look for an example. This is a security risk(same as download checks with md5). See http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value for more information. If you use MD5 for instance to auto login you can imagine the security flaw ;)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus PHP5.4 What do you mean by saying everywhere?

Comment: @survex Everywhere = Web browser, PHP, Database. Can anyone else think of something I am missing?

Comment: @survex Could you output every value of your database with `var_dump`(as John Conde already mentioned). And why are you comparing strings instead of comparing keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that your strings have some characters that aren't visible.

Consider the following:

```
$a = "abc";
$b = "abc\0";
echo (int)( $a == $b );
```

This will echo `0`.

But, if you echo `$a` and `$b`, you will **see** `"abc"`.

---

Another possibility **might** be that you are reading/writting a file using `fopen()` without the `b` option.

Windows has a feature that converts `\r` and `\n` into `\r\n`.

When you read back, it comes with Windows' line endings.

When you compare, the values are different, since `\r` (in memory/cookie) isn't the same as `\r\n` (read from the file).

When you output it to a **browser**, it is shown as `abc`. Browsers ignore whitespaces in the output (changeable with CSS).

---

**Another** thing might be implicit numeric convertion.

Consider the following code:

```
echo '1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' == '1.0E+48';
```

This will echo `1`. Check it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1debf1a505793e3d0fde3b174c26e1f1454ea1e2

Using `===` solves this.

Something similar might be happening. But this shows the oposite (2 different strings that aren't equal being compared that returns `true`).

---

The source and the environment itself are unknown.

How the values are obtained is unknown as well.

There are too many unknowns...

Comment: I think this is pretty much it! Now I have reproduced the bug and tomorrow I'll deploy changes. What you think is the best way to escape such problem?

Comment: @survex Filter the cookies with `trim()` before comparing them. This function removes the most common invisible symbols from the beginning and the end of a string.

Comment: @survex There are many unknowns. I don't know where was the `$prevCookie` stored before. I don't know what comes in `$currentCookie`. But the best would be to `trim()` and to use `str_replace("\0",'',$cookie)`. Also, use `===`instead.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel No need to enforce type comparison when he is explicitly casting both variables to `(string)`.

Comment: @Havenard http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1debf1a505793e3d0fde3b174c26e1f1454ea1e2 --> this proves you wrong. Try running this: `echo '1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' == '1.0E+48';` (should output `1`).

Comment: @Havenard I added it to the answer as a possibility. You need to be really careful with string comparisson.

Answer (score 0):

Use [strcmp](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strcmp.asp) (case sensitive) or [strcasecmp](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strcasecmp.asp) (case insensitive).

For string compare, in most of languages, is not a good solution use direct compare to strings.

```
echo 'prev: ' . $prevCookie;
echo 'curr: ' . $currentCookie;
if (strcmp($prevCookie,$currentCookie) === 0) {
  echo 'same cookies';
} else {
  echo 'different cookies';
}
```

Comment: I don't see how using  `strcmp()` it will produce any different behaviour compared to using `==`.

Comment: If the function exists means that the equals `==` will check if the variable is the same, not the same value.

Comment: Nothing wrong about comparing them as far as I know. Whats to be avoided is to check if a string is empty with `if ($string)`, because the interpreter will understand this as `if ((bool)$string)` and if the string is not empty, but is equal to `"0"` or `"0000"` it will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: @Havenard There are other dangers. Try running this: `echo '1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' == '1.0E+48';` (it will echo `1`, while it should echo nothing at all). The string `'1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'` will be converted to the integer `1.0E+48`, while the string `'1.0E+48'` will be converted to the same exact value. Using `===` or `strcmp()` will solve this.

Answer (score -3):

Sometimes when debuggin the ide shows the same value but for example if you are comparing a global value inside function and you do not have declare the result will not be the same example

Not work

```
function compare($p){
  return $p == $z;
}
```

Will work

```
function compare($p){
global $z;
return $p == $z;
}
```