# php string match check is not getting the expected result

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, if-statement

I am trying to use php to check if two strings are matching, if they do, then do something.

But my if statement keeps returning false, even though they match.

Look at my VIEW file. before the if statement, I even used echo just to see what they are.

What am I missing? Is it something to do with angularjs???

By the way, `echo $type . " " . '{{ post.postType }}';` actually results this:

```
<!-- The View -->
<body ng-app"myApp">
<div class="container testing" ng-controller="feedControl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <td style="padding:15px">{{ post.postType }}</td>
        <td style="padding:15px">{{ post.postTitle }}</td>
        <td style="padding:15px">{{ post.postDescription }}</td>
        <td style="padding:15px">{{ post.postDate }}</td>
        <td style="padding:15px">
        <?php
        $type = '{{ post.postType }}';

        echo $type . " " . '{{ post.postType }}';

        if($type == 'image'){
                 echo $type . " " . '{{ post.postType }}';
        };
        ?>
    </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</div>
</body>




<!-- feed.php -->
<?php

    include 'db.php';

    connection();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM feed ORDER BY time DESC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $outp = "";
    while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}

        $source = "";
        if($rs["post_type"] == "video"){
            $source = str_replace('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="', '', $rs["src"]);
            $source = str_replace('" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>', '', $source);
        }
        if($rs["post_type"] == "music"){
            $source = str_replace('<iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="', '', $rs["src"]);
            $source = str_replace('"></iframe>', '', $source);
        }
        if($rs["post_type"] == "image"){
            $source = $rs["src"];
        }


        $outp .= '{"postType":"'  . $rs["post_type"] . '",';
        $outp .= '"postDate":"'   . $rs["time"]        . '",';
        $outp .= '"postTitle":"'   . $rs["post_title"]        . '",';
        $outp .= '"src":"'   . $source        . '",';
        $outp .= '"postDescription":"'. $rs["post_description"]     . '"}';
    }
    $outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';


    connectionClose();

    echo($outp);

?>




<!-- module -->
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

<!-- controller -->
app.controller('feedControl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("pages/db_section/feed.php")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.posts = response.data.records;
    });
});
```

Comment: could you share the actual result of this `echo $type . " " . '{{ post.postType }}';` ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted that at the beginning. It actually results this:

image image

Comment: please also check PHP `strcmp` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php, to understand how it works also check this comment http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php#110975.

Comment: a similar question is also this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562703/make-encoding-uniform-before-comparing-strings-in-php

Comment: So I saw the similar question post and applied that string comparison. It resulted that $type has 19 characters and image has 5. So my if statement is actually comparing the input reference of $type, not the actual retrieved value(which is also image).
If this is the case, how do I actually compare with $type retrieved value????

Comment: Why do you think templating inside PHP should work?

`$type = '{{ post.postType }}';` will be read as is.

Comment: now I see what went wrong! but still I don't know how I can actually fix this. because if I try to remove the quotation marks from $type = '{{ post.postType }}'; it gives me an error.

Comment: What is `post` by the way? A PHP variable passed to the view? Is it an object?

Comment: It is. it is refering to this code: <tr ng-repeat="post in posts">

Comment: ok, I am `not` much familiar with Angular, but if `posts` is something that has values and is executed in the browser with the help of Angular JS, then you will not be able to use this on the server side in PHP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171397/discussion-between-al-nafis-and-vivek-23).